# show that$ U=\{(x,y) \text{is an element of} \mathbb{R^2}:x^2+4y^2<4\}$ is open by finding a ball around each point which is contained in U

Tags: calculus

I am trying to figure out how to do this one.I know that it is an open set but I don't know how to prove that it is open. I know how to show the ball around each point contained in U but not the overall graph of the ball and what I need to show that it is open.

Comment: Are you saying that you can already, for any $u\in U$ demonstrate that there's some ball $B$ centered at $u$ and contained in $U$? Because that's the definition of open.

Answer (score -2):

For any point in U there is a minimum distance to the boundary of the ellipse which is > 0. Just make your neighborhood smaller than that value and it will be open.

Comment: What do you mean by neighbourhood?

Comment: A neighborhood is the same as a ball in this case.

Comment: how do I know which points to find the ball around?

Comment: It's the points that I said in the answer above.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I just really don't understand how to show this